# constructive type theory books

Tags: logic, reference-request, type-theory, constructive-mathematics

What is the best book you recommend for a beginner in constructive type theory applied to computer science?

Comment: Nordström, Bengt, Kent Petersson, and Jan M. Smith, 1990, Programming in Martin-Löf’s type theory. An introduction, New York: Oxford University Press.